# Cart speed and wheel rotation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, velocity, projectile

Say you have a horse drawn cart.  Does the outside of the wheel spin at the same velocity that the cart moves forward?

The reason I ask is because I am working on a problem where a piece of mud detaches from the wheel when it is moving up, and then lands on the wheel again at the same spot.  I don't see how this is even possible, though, if the cart moves forward at the same velocity that the wheel turns because some of the velocity in the mud will be in the y direction so it could never match the speed of the cart, much less beat it.

Comment: This should probably be under homework and exercises. Some hints: 1. Velocity with respect to what? 2. Do all the parts of the wheel have the same velocity? 3. Think about the part of the wheel touching the ground - what must be its velocity with respect to the ground?

Comment: I just provided the second paragraph for some context - but I guess it kind of turned into a question of its own.  My real question is in the first sentence.

Comment: A circular motion is not the same as a linear motion, so your question should say "is the velocity of the rim of the wheel the same as the velocity of the cart?" The bottom of the wheel does not move along the ground (otherwise it would slide or spin against the ground).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rate at which the wheel is spinning is an angular velocity, normally measured in radians/second.  The velocity of the cart is a linear velocity - metres/second in SI units.  Since the two are different units, they can't really be compared.

However, you can calculate the instantaneous velocity of any given part of the wheel rim.  Unless the wheels are jammed, and the horse is simply dragging the cart along, this will definitely not be the same for each part of the wheel rim.  As user27118 hints, a good start is to consider the instantaneous velocity of the bottom of the wheel.